# Regex to check for single/double quotation marks and parenthesis?

Tags: php, regex

I need to have make some kind of filter that doesn't allow the user to use the following characters in a password:

```
" ' ( )
```

Right now the only code I got is the following:

```
if(preg_match('/"/', $password)) {
    echo "illegal character found..";
}
```

I'm extremely bad with Regex and any kind of help is appreciated, I've been looking around for answers but can't seem to find any that both checks for single and double quotation marks..

Comment: Hm, I wrote you an answer, the task is quite simply. Question is, why you want to disable these characters? You `hash` passwords, so don't worry to allow all characters in password. It's non-sense restriction.

Comment: if you save only encrypted password, you wont need that regexp.

Comment: @panther I'm not going too save the password in a database, or well yes I will but I'll pass it forward to another server to handle all that, and the method I'll be doing so with is extremely old and bad so I need to take care of all the work in php itself.

Comment: @Denniz: it's the right time to write the login part of application once again, and better :-)

Comment: @panther I'm using it to make powershell commands so I can add users to Active Directory, and I couldn't really find a good way to do it good and with as many options I wanted with LDAP that's why. And the method is pretty unsecure really but I just want to get everything to work as soon as possible and then move on by securing it etc! Thank you very much for your help Panther really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match('~[\'"\(\)]~', $password); // return true when any of '"() is in password.
```

The whole code should be:

```
$password = '...';
if (preg_match('~[\'"\(\)]~', $password)) {
    echo 'password contains bad character';
} else {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following rule:

```
if(preg_match("/[\(\)\'\"]/", $text) !== FALSE)
{
   // show error
}
```

You can be more creative by showing which character has illegally been used:

```
$result = NULL;
if(preg_match("/([\(\)\'\"])/", $text, $result) !== FALSE)
{
   echo "You have used illegal character " . $result[0] . "in your text";
}
```

Note I have changed the RegEx rule a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

This should work;

```
["'\/\(\)]
```

You want to catch any of paranthesis or slashes or quotes, so you need to use a character class. 
A character class is defined by `[]` and it basically means any of the characters that are inside these brackets.

Also parantheses and forward slashes have a special meaning in regexes, so you should escape them with a `\`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match

```
['"\(\)]
```

i.e:

```
if(preg_match("/['\"\(\)]/", $password)) {
    echo "illegal character found..";
}
```